# heroku cli でwarをデプロイした際にjava versionを指定する方法

Tags: java, heroku

herokuでgitを使わずに、warをCLIを通じてデプロイしています。
その際にjava versionを指定したいのですが　そのような方法はないでしょうか？
gitで`system.properties`を利用しないで実現したいです。

Answer (score 0):

カレントディレクトリ(`heroku`コマンドを実行するディレクトリ)に `system.properties` ファイルを置いておけば認識されたかと思います。

Comment: すごーーーい！！！！！

Comment: できました　herokuに問い合わせしても　出来ないということだったのに！！！！！　本当にありがとうございました！！！！　本当に助かりました！！！！